# Does $X_n$ iid $\sim Bern(1/2)$ converge almost surely to anything?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables

Does $X_n$ iid $\sim Bern(1/2)$ converge to anything?

I feel like iid $Bern(1/2)$ random variables does not converge to anything since it takes value $1$ and $0$ each with probability $1/2$. Therefore, the resulting sequence will be oscillating between $1$ and $0$.

However, if we define $X_n(\omega) $ as follows,

\begin{equation}
    X_n(\omega)=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ \omega=T\\
      1, & \text{if}\ \omega = H
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

assuming a fair coin,  and check $Pr(\omega\in \Omega: \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega))$, we see that $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(H) = X(H)$ and $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(T) = X(T)$. Therefore, $Pr(\omega\in \Omega: \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)) = 1$. So we do have almost sure convergence.

Which one is true? Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If $X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)$ for all $n$, how do you have independence?

Comment: @TrevorGunn but even remove this statement... it won't affect the argument.

Comment: It depends on what kind of convergence you mean. A sequence of iid random variables with distribution $X$ converges to $X$ in probability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I meant convergence almost surely

Comment: A sequence of iid bernoulli random variables will almost surely *not* converge (nor does it converge in probability). A constant sequence is not independent but of course will converge.

Comment: @TrevorGunn   but isn't $X_n(\omega)$ defined this way? you look at each $\omega$ and see if we have pointwise convergnce a.s.?

Comment: Is $X_n(\omega)$ defined? Of course it's defined. You defined it.

Comment: @TrevorGunn but how should you define a sequence of iid bernoulli random variables....?

Comment: The classic example is to write a number $\omega \in [0,1]$ as $0.X_1(\omega)X_2(\omega)\cdots$ in base $2$. The set of numbers that have more than one representation in base $2$ is countable (measure $0$).

Comment: @TrevorGunn how would you define the mapping from sample space to real?

Comment: $X_n(\omega)$ is the $n$-th digit in the base $2$ representation of $\omega$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn but how would you interpret the almost sure convergence definition? we need to check for almost every point in the sample space, if we have convergence...right?

Comment: And there are only countably many points where the sequence converges (the numbers that end with a string of zeros or ones). So the sequence does not converge with probability 1.

Comment: Of course an iid sequence of Bernoulli(1/2) will **not** converge to anything almost surely. The sequence you have defined is constant, not iid.

Comment: @Shalop the sample space has only two points, how do you define almost surely convergence on sample space?